# Negar dos caracteres en una consulta

Tags: sql-server

Una pregunta, debo devolver valores de una segunda serie que no contengan 1 y 7.
Por ejemplo: `256-08-36` o `369-68-41` (ambos números del medio no tienen 1 y 7)

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT autor_id
FROM autores
WHERE autor_id LIKE '[7-9]____[^1,7]%'
```

Me sigue apareciendo el numero 7, el 1 no se muestra. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para verificar la serie central, puedes usar el siguiente patrón:

```
WHERE autor_id LIKE '%-[^17][^17]-%'
```

Los corchetes `[]` especifican un único caracter, en este caso estamos negando que el primero y segundo caracter sean 1 o 7.

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un subrayado de más.

```
SELECT autor_id
FROM (
    values
         ('256-08-36')
        ,('369-68-41')
        ,('723-25-18') -- empieza por siete y no contiene en medio ni uno ni siete
        ,('923-34-27') -- empieza por nueve y no contiene en medio ni uno ni siete
        ,('811-00-11') -- empieza por ocho y no contiene en medio ni uno ni siete
        ,('811-01-11')
        ,('811-12-11')
        ,('811-72-11')
        ,('811-27-11')
        ,('811-29-11')-- empieza por siete y no contiene en medio ni uno ni siete
        ) 
    autores(autor_id)

WHERE autor_id LIKE '[7-9]___[^1,7][^1,7]%'
```

En la serie del medio no tienes ni uno ni siete en los caracteres de las posiciones entre los guiones.

[image: resultado]

Esa podría ser una solución

Comment: genial gracias!!! en mysql seria la misma sintaxis?? o cambia

Comment: Yo diría que no. Que en mysql cambia, aunque se puede utilizar RegexLike. Puedes echarle un ojo a la pagina oficial de MySql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: ok muchisimas gracias!